# IntelliJ-IDEA: Where are settings files saved for v11.x on Windows 7?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I load/save settings on my PC for IntelliJ-IDEA v11+ Ultimate on Windows 7, it is super slow (seconds).  I think the settings are being saved on a network drive (corporate setup), but I want to confirm.

1. What is the default location on Windows 7 for IntelliJ-IDEA settings files?
2. How can I change the location of settings files?

**UPDATE**

I checked my `idea.properties` file here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.5\bin\idea.properties`.  I see this entry (commented-out):

```
# idea.config.path=${user.home}/.IntelliJIdea/config
```

My insane corporate setup has Java's `user.home` mapped to `\\UBSPROD.MSAD.UBS.NET\UserData\arpeke\RF`.  There, I found the folder named `.IntelliJIdea` with my settings.

Comment: There is a [KB document](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23348963) about how to change the liocation of IDEA folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Props to Ryan for the hint I needed.  Posting a detailed answer here, because I could not find the answer anywhere else on the Net.

1. Discover your Java's `user.home` System property settings.

   - See this Q&A: [On Windows 7, how does Java JVM set "user.home" System property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889940/on-windows-7-how-does-java-jvm-set-user-home-system-property)
   - Or, try in an Java IDE: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));`
   - You may surprised by its value!
   - Let us suppose it is `C:\Users\user123`
2. There, you will find a folder named `.IntelliJIdea`, and sub-folder within named `config`.
3. If the `.IntelliJIdea` folder is stored on a network drive, you may find IntelliJ performance less than ideal.
4. Modify your `idea.properties` file.  Possible full path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.5\bin\idea.properties`
5. Modify options for config, system, plugins, and logs.  Example: `idea.config.path=${user.home}/.IntelliJIdea/config` => `idea.config.path=c:/local/path/.IntelliJIdea/config`

**Update**

Official Knowledge Base article from JetBrains: http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23348963

Answer (score 5):

IntelliJ saves its config and indexes, which can amount to several gigs worth of data, to your home directory. It's been that way for approximately "a long time". In my experience, if you have default network mounts, your home dir will be set to one of those, so that's very likely your problem. Edit `<idea dir>/bin/idea.properties` to change the location where it saves stuff. There will be a handful of properties to change because it calls things out individually rather than having one, overall directory.