# Javaws application is taking long time to launch

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, java-web-start

I am running javaws application on windows 7 professional with java 1.7u21 it is taking a very long time greater than 1 minute , even launching application is taking a long time about 40 sec means org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.main is using high cpu and taking long time.

As analysed org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.main method is taking much time

Tomcat is also taking very long time even meta-complete is true so scanning is off.

.[image]

Does anyone know why the application is taking such a long time?

Comment: I've had problems with my JWS apps taking forever to load, and it was always related to my build scripts (auto-generated by Netbeans) being out of whack. Usually this happens when I update my version of Netbeans. The solution is to delete the `jnlp-impl.xml` that Netbeans auto-generates. But you have Eclipse, so I'm not sure if this'll help you.

Comment: Is your application running significantly faster when you start it as stand-alone (i.e. out of a Java Web Start environment)?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue with webstarting an Eclipse application on Windows. It turned out that the Java system property "user.home" was set to a network drive, this is a [known bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889940/on-windows-7-how-does-java-jvm-set-user-home-system-property). The Eclipse webstart example jnlp's are configured to install the application below the user.home folder. This can take a very long time on a network drive. I solved the issue by creating a custom class WebStartLauncher with a main method that sets user.home to %LOCALAPPDATA% before passing control to the normal Eclipse WebStartMain:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userProfile = System.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA");
        if (userProfile != null) {
            System.setProperty("user.home", userProfile);
        }
        WebStartMain.main(args);
    }
```