# ClassNotFoundException HttpServletRequest when changing permissions for everybody, java.io.File

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to set permissions to a file because I'm getting warnings and a NoClassDefFoundError after that, I tried using

```
file.setWritable(true,false);
file.setExecutable(true,false);
file.setReadable(true,false);
```

But doesn't work, the file is created this way:

```
private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR
        = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".store/calendar_sample");
```

This is for Google Calendar V3 API, i'm using a Mac, and here the project executes with no problem, but when I run it in a Windows 7 the problem start to show and the .jar crashes

The Exception seems to trigger when the file don't have the permissions.

this is the whole class

```
public class GoogleCalendar2 {

private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "expeDiente";
private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR
        = new java.io.File("C:\\\\\\\\", ".store/calendar_sample");
private static FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory;
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
private static HttpTransport httpTransport;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static Calendar client;
String id = "";

public GoogleCalendar2() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, Exception {
    DATA_STORE_DIR.setWritable(true, false);
    DATA_STORE_DIR.setExecutable(true, false);
    DATA_STORE_DIR.setReadable(true, false);

    httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

    dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);

    Credential credential = authorize();

    client = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

}

/**
 * Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected data.
 */
private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
    Set<String> scopes = new HashSet<String>();
    scopes.add(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR);
    scopes.add(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_READONLY);

    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, "user id google", "user secrets", scopes)
            .setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
            .build();
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
 }
}
```

this is what I get when I try to run the jar
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the problem that Java is unable to resolve the system property `"user.home"` on Windows 7. On Unix and Unix-like OS, this property value will be evaluated to be the environment variable `$HOME` such as `/home/my_username`. However, on Windows 7, Java does not interpret it to be the default user directory `C:\User\my_username`. More details can be found from the related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889940/on-windows-7-how-does-java-jvm-set-user-home-system-property).

Comment: I tried using user.dir and i'm still getting the same warnings.

Comment: like using C:\ as directory? I don't get what's 'hard coded' way

Comment: Yes, but in Java you need to put something like "C:\\\\".

Comment: Ok, if I was using System.getProperty("user.home"), ".store/calendar_sample" AND changed to "C:\\\\\\\\", ".store/calendar_sample" and I'm getting the same warning, It seems doesn't work

Comment: When you debugged your program, did you see the file `C:\.store\calendar_sample` is being created when you call that line? Also it should be "C:\\", just two back slashes.

Comment: yes, I debugged it and the directory and the file is created every time I run the project

Comment: I don't see any problems then based on your code. Can you post your full code?

Comment: Where does the NoClassDefFoundError occur from the stack trace?

Comment: in this line: return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user") in autorize() method, when the dataStoreFactory is not working well it throw the exception, in the Mac, it doesnt happen, I checked the classpath and all the jars are my lib folder too.